# Some questions about jdk nio SelectionKey

Tags: java, nio

Recently, I had a problem reading the jdk 1.8 nio source code. I wonder what the difference between these two properties is? Based on my query, some people say that publicKeys is a proxy enhancement to keys, but I found that it is possible to add elements to keys, but publicKeys is immutable, how should this be understood.

```
public abstract class SelectorImpl extends AbstractSelector {
    protected HashSet<SelectionKey> keys = new HashSet();
    private Set<SelectionKey> publicKeys;

    
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you are referring to `sun.nio.ch.SelectorImpl`, `publicKeys` is declared as private and assigned as follows in the constructor:
`publicKeys = Collections.unmodifiableSet(keys)`.

Taking a look at `Collections#unmodifiableSet(Set)` we see that this provides "read-only" access to its argument. It does NOT behave like a copy constructor, i.e. copying element references and providing a static view of the original at the time the method is invoked. Rather, it provides a dynamic `Set` view of the original, where all `Set` modification methods (e.g. `add`, `clear`) throw an exception.

Comment: `publicKeys` is a _dynamic_ read-only view of `keys`. When `keys` is updated, `publicKeys` reflects the change. The sense in which `publicKeys` can not be changed is that it can not be changed by you, the caller. It is private so you can't re-assign it, and when you call `keys()` any attempt to modify the returned `Set` (which is `publicKeys`) will result in an error thrown. But reading from the returned `Set` will reflect any updates made to `keys`